# Javascript Error in Localization

Tags: javascript, json, html, localization, xmlhttprequest

I have recently started working on javascript and json. I am trying to implement localization where I can support multiple languages using json files. The javascript file **i18n.js library** provides translation helper functions and is available on net. The error which I am facing is

> Uncaught Exception:NETWORK_ERROR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101.

This error is thrown when we try to send the `request.open()` method is called with url passed is `local(lang/de.json)`. Even though I am not sending my request to any web url its throwing this error.

Any help will be great for me. If more details are needed I can post it further.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is this a cross-domain request (google "same origin policy")? If it's requesting file from remote domain, you need to use JSONP technique. Otherwise I'm not sure without further information (rest of the code you have in context, server side code maybe...) can you debug it with a javascript console (firebug)?

Comment: Thanks Brandon for the important point. I have to check whether it is requesting file from remote domain. Is there any other method or tool other than firebug to find out about this cross domain request(origin policy)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error you are describing is indicative of a cross domain request that the DOM can't access. Firebug would likely give you the same error, but you can look at the XHR requests in the console as it's being sent and see what URL it's going to. It would also indicate any issues you are having in your javascript if they are syntax errors or DOM issues.